Does duality hold for u(x, y) = x^2 + y^2? (Corner solution)
Could you please help me evaluate this logic?
I've been told that "if preferences are strongly monotonic, duality holds."
In the case of utility u(x,y) = x^2 + y^2, we will get a corner solution depending on the relative price of x and y. Suppose p_x > p_y => x* = 0.
Then MUx = 0 at x*, so preferences are not strongly monotonic around the optimum. Hence, duality may not hold (Hicksian demand ≠ Marshallian demand). After plugging in the indirect utility function into Hicksian demand, I found that indeed duality does not hold here.
Does duality hold? If yes, please show why mathematically.

This utility function is strongly monotonic.

Not globally though? Marginal utility is equal to zero for x or y equal to zero, which is exactly the interesting case? Although this may not be the formal definition of strong monotonicity, I feel like it interferes with duality here. Do you think duality holds?

You could actually provide your calculations. Your utility function is strictly increasing everywhere. A strictly positive derivative everywhere is a sufficient but not necessary condition for a function to be strictly increasing.

The Marshallian demand correspondence is given by:
$$
x(p_x, p_y,m) = \begin{cases} \{m/p_x\} &\text{ if } p_x < p_y\\ \{0, m/p_x\} &\text{ if } p_x = p_y\\ \{0\} &\text{ if } p_x > p_y \end{cases}.
$$
The indirect utility function is given by:
$$
v(p_x, p_y, m) = \left(\frac{m}{\min\{p_x, p_y\}}\right)^2
$$
Now consider the cost minimization problem:
$$
e(p_x, p_y, \bar u) = \min p_x x + p_y y \text{ s.t. } x^2 + y^2 \ge \bar u.
$$
If $p_x < p_y$ it will be best to set $x = \sqrt{\bar u}$ and if $p_y < p_x$ it will be best to set $y = \sqrt{\bar u}$. So we get that the Hicksian demand correspondence is given by:
$$
h_x(p_x, p_y, \bar u) = \begin{cases}\{\sqrt{\bar u}\} & \text{ if } p_x < p_y,\\ \{0, \sqrt{\bar u}\} \text{ if } p_x = p_y,\\ \{0\} &\text{ if } p_x > p_y\end{cases}.
$$
The expenditure function is given by:
$$
e(p_x, p_y, \bar u) = \min\{p_x, p_y\}\sqrt{\bar u}.
$$
Now, if $p_x < p_y$ then:
$$
h_x(p_x, p_y, v(p_x, p_y, m)) = \left\{\sqrt{v(p_x, p_y, m)}\right\} = \left\{\frac{m}{\min\{p_x, p_y\}}\right\} = \left\{\frac{m}{p_x}\right\} = x(p_x, p_y, m).
$$
If $p_x > p_y$ then:
$$
h_x(p_x, p_y, v(p_x, p_y, m)) = \{0\} = x(p_x, p_y, m)
$$
If $p_x = p_y$ we have:
$$
h_x(p_x, p_y, v(p_x,p_y,m)) = \left\{0, \sqrt{v(p_x, p_y, m)}\right\} = \left\{0, \frac{m}{p_x}\right\} = x(p_x, p_y, m).
$$
This shows that strong duality does hold in this case.
The conceptual difficulty for this example is that if $p_x = p_y$, then demand is not single-valued. As such, we have to work with demand correspondences rather than demand functions.

Wow thank you for this thorough answer! I completely missed that method for deriving Hicksian demand!

I'm posting here, because I don't have enough reputation points to just comment. So, if I understand this correctly, monotonic means that preferences, do not change, right? Like, I'm familiar with the concept of monotonic transformation, but what do you mean by duality? Also, is there a scenario, where preferences are not monotonic?
I don't mean to be rude. I genuinely want to know.
Also, pls don't feel like you need to write long paragraphs to explain it (although that would be great), if you could recommend a video or an article I would really appreciate it too.
